# PostgreSQL: server process was terminated by Hungup

Tags: postgresql, docker

PostgreSQL 13.11 (Debian 13.11-1.pgdg110+1) in docker container.

shared_buffers = 1GB, work_mem = 4MB, maintenance_work_mem = 128MB

On application side we have a error:

```
Error querying database.  Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: An
I/O error occurred while sending to the backend.
```

In PostgreSQL log:

```
User: ; Session: 646b7e69.1; DB: ; Host: LOG: server process (PID
339174) was terminated by signal 1: Hangup 
 
User: ; Session: 646b7e69.1; DB: ; Host: LOG: terminating any other
active server processes 
 
User: postgres; Session: 647d6362.52d1d; DB: database_name; Host:
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx(43668) WARNING: terminating connection because of
crash of another server process 
 
User: postgres; Session: 647d6362.52d1d; DB: database_name; Host:
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx(43668) DETAIL: The postmaster has commanded this
server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because
another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared
memory. 
 
User: postgres; Session: 647d6362.52d1d; DB: database_name; Host:
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx(43668) HINT: In a moment you should be able to
reconnect to the database and repeat your command. 
 
User: postgres; Session: 647d6360.52d19; DB: database_name; Host:
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx(43664) 
WARNING: terminating connection because of
crash of another server process 
 
User: postgres; Session: 647d6360.52d19; DB: database_name; Host:
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx(43664) 
DETAIL: The postmaster has commanded this
server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, 
because another server process exited abnormally and possibly 
corrupted shared memory. 
 
User: postgres; Session: 647d6360.52d19; DB: database_name; Host:
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx(43664) 
HINT: In a moment you should be able to
reconnect to the database and repeat your command. 
 
... 
 
User: postgres; Session: 647d6360.52d1a; DB: database_name; Host:
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx(43666) 
WARNING: terminating connection because of
crash of another server process 
 
User: postgres; Session: 647d6360.52d1a; DB: database_name; Host:
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx(43666) 
DETAIL: The postmaster has commanded this
server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, 
because
another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted 
shared
memory. 
 
User: postgres; Session: 647d6360.52d1a; DB: database_name; Host:
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx(43666) HINT: In a moment you should be able to
reconnect to the database and repeat your command. 
 
User: ; Session: 646b7e69.1; DB: ; Host: LOG: all server processes
terminated; reinitializing 
 
User: ; Session: 647d6363.52d1e; DB: ; Host: LOG: database system was
interrupted; last known up at 
 
User: ; Session: 647d6363.52d1e; DB: ; Host: LOG: database system was
not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress 
 
User: ; Session: 647d6363.52d1e; DB: ; Host: LOG: redo starts at
1D3F/32006430 
 
User: postgres; Session: 647d6363.52d20; DB: database_name; Host:
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx(33586) FATAL: the database system is in recovery mode 
 
User: postgres; Session: 647d6363.52d21; DB: database_name; Host:
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx(43670) FATAL: the database system is in recovery mode 
 
User: postgres; Session: 647d6364.52d22; DB: database_name; Host:
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx(33588) FATAL: the database system is in recovery mode 
 
User: postgres; Session: 647d6364.52d23; DB: database_name; Host:
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx(43672) FATAL: the database system is in recovery mode 
 
User: postgres; Session: 647d6364.52d24; DB: database_name; Host:
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx(49368) FATAL: the database system is in recovery mode
 
... 
 
User: postgres; Session: 647d6364.52d24; DB: database_name; Host:
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx(49368) FATAL: the database system is in recovery mode 
 
User: ; Session: 647d6363.52d1e; DB: ; Host: LOG: invalid record
length at 1D3F/5A7A9510: wanted 24, got 0 User: ; Session:
647d6363.52d1e; DB: ; Host: LOG: redo done at 1D3F/5A7A94D8 
 
User: ; Session: 647d6363.52d1e; DB: ; Host: LOG: checkpoint starting:
end-of-recovery immediate 
 
User: ; Session: 647d6363.52d1e; DB: ; Host: LOG: checkpoint complete:
wrote 15226 buffers (92.9%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 40
recycled; write=0.295 s, sync=0.259 s, total=0.619 s; sync files=142,
longest=0.058 s, average=0.002 s; distance=663180 kB, estimate=663180kB 
 
User: ; Session: 646b7e69.1; DB: ; Host: LOG: database system is ready
to accept connections
```

The database accessed by the failed service is very small (about30MB). Other services
that connect to other databases on this PostgreSQL server work successfully.

How to understand the reason for this hangup process?
As far as I can see, the OOM-killer did not occur.

Comment: You would normally use a SIGHUP to reload config files. Could someone/something be sending the signal to a backend process handling connections rather than the parent PID by mistake?

Comment: I think it's unlikely

Comment: That doesn't look quite like a postgresql log file, although it surely has some snippets of one embedded in it. Had it been ingested into something else?  I would think the root error would have been described just before the start of the excerpt you posted.

Comment: No, that is postgresql log without timestamps. It was only automatic vacuum about 30s before error. Thats all.